# Cassandra Function not implemented

Tags: cassandra, copy

Anybody know why I got this error:

```
Using 15 child processes
[Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

I always see when I want perform COPY FROM command.
I use Cassandra 3.7.0

Comment: Can you show the COPY FROM command you are executing?

Comment: This sounds like a system error. Platform and Python runtime information might be pertinent.

Comment: Copy keyspace,tableName (columnName) FROM 'file.csv' this command I executing